How to get roblox csrf-token 2024 node.js
Does anyone know how to get your csrf-token on roblox in 2024, I use
to know back in 2022 but it doesn't seem to work.
import axios from 'axios'

const cookie = ".ROBLOSECURITY="+'_|WARNING:-DO-NOT-SHARE-THIS.--Sharing-this-will-allow-someone-to-log-in-as-you-and-to-steal-your-ROBUX-and-items.|_

axios.post('https://auth.roblox.com/v2/logout', null, {
    headers: {
        'Cookie': cookie
    }
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.headers);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
});

I want to get the csrf-token by requesting to an api endpoint of roblox that still has it
